# Uniformly random matrices in SO(n)

Tags: random-matrices, orthogonal-matrices

I don't know whether this question fits best on StackOverflow, Math.SE or CrossValidated; **I am looking for a practical algorithm to generate uniformly distributed matrices in $SO(n,\mathbb{R})$** (aka uniformly random rotation matrices in dimension $n$). [This answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/143970/44129) goes into rather lengthy explanations without giving a clear "recipe", and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix#Randomization) provides a description for which I am struggling to find an implementation:

> Stewart (1980) replaced this with a more efficient idea that Diaconis
>   & Shahshahani (1987) later generalized as the "subgroup algorithm" (in
>   which form it works just as well for permutations and rotations). To
>   generate an (n + 1) × (n + 1) orthogonal matrix, take an n × n one and
>   a uniformly distributed unit vector of dimension n + 1. Construct a
>   Householder reflection from the vector, then apply it to the smaller
>   matrix (embedded in the larger size with a 1 at the bottom right
>   corner).

As far as I understand, this would be equivalent to (but more efficient than) the following (Matlab language):

```
Q = randn(n); % uniformly random entries
Q = Q * diag(sign(diag(Q))); % flip column signs to have positive diagonal
Q = orth(Q); % orthogonalise
Q = Q / det(Q)^(1/n); % unit determinant
```

I am asking: i) whether the previous indeed generates uniformly distributed matrices in $SO(n)$; and ii) whether someone could provide a practical implementation of the algorithm described on Wikipedia (quoted above).

Comment: This shoud be the same as picking a random point on the sphere $S^n$. Or the same as picking $n-1$ Euler angles (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles) uniformly at random.

Comment: I don't think it is the same as picking random point on $S^n$; the idea then is to realise that the level sets of isotropic normal distributions are n-spheres, and so normalised samples from a normal distribution are uniformly distributed on the sphere (exploiting the "isotropy"). How does that relate to uniformly random rotations?

Comment: A random point on $S^n$ gives an axis of rotation and an element of $SO(n)$ once a further angle is chosen, doesn't it?

Comment: Now I get it :) Yes of course you are right. So then we are looking at higher-dimensional counterparts of quaternions?

Comment: I guess so, essentially. The main issue is that not every element of $SO(4)$ is a rotation around an axis. The last paragraph https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotations_in_4-dimensional_Euclidean_space is relevant.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio "Axis of rotation" doesn't make sense in dimensions other than 3. It doesn't even make sense in 2 dimensions.